# Passenger: cannot load such file rubygems/builder

Tags: ruby, apache, passenger

I was trying to install passenger with Apache2 and ruby 2.0, and I had this line of error when I am doing:

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Error:

```
--------------------------------------------
Compiling and installing Apache 2 module...
cd /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-3.0.19
/usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/rake apache2:clean apache2 RELEASE=yes
# /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/rake apache2:clean apache2 RELEASE=yes
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- rubygems/builder

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

--------------------------------------------

It looks like something went wrong
```

I tried:

```
gem install builder
```

But this error still occurs. How can I solve it?

---

**Edit**

Ruby Version:

```
2.0 p2
```

Gem List:

```
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
builder (3.2.0)
bundler (1.3.1)
daemon_controller (1.1.1)
fastthread (1.0.7)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
minitest (4.3.2)
passenger (3.0.19)
psych (2.0.0)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-protection (1.4.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
sinatra (1.3.5)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
tilt (1.3.4)
```

Comment: Which version of both Ruby and Passenger are you using?

Comment: let me know if the offered solution helps.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Updated instructions:

```
$ gem install passenger --version 4.0.0.rc6
$ passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Comment: I tried, and got this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328326/passenger-internal-server-error

Comment: Your post got me past `cannot load such file -- rubygems/builder`—gracias.

Answer (score 8):

There's seems to be problems with Ruby 2.0 and passenger as pointed on this reported issue:[Passenger Ruby 2.0 issue](https://github.com/FooBarWidget/passenger/pull/71)

One of the proposed solutions (can be found on one of the comments there):

```
git clone https://github.com/FooBarWidget/passenger.git
cd passenger
gem build passenger.gemspec
gem install passenger-3.9.5.rc3.gem (or type your actual built gem name)
```

**Edit:**

To simplify the process a pre-release version (pointing to whatever latest RC version) can also be installed in the following fashion:

```
gem install passenger --pre
```

Comment: Worked for me, ticket should be close on next rc.