# Passenger: An error occurred while starting up the preloader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I've tried what was recommended here: [Passenger: internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328326/passenger-internal-server-error) , but found no references to STDOUT in config.ru

I'm on ruby-2.0.0-p247 and passenger (4.0.17)

Console output after attempting to load page:

> [ 2013-09-16 14:34:07.3648 4197/b72beb40 Pool2/Spawner.h:738 ]: [App 4435 stdout] 
>   Connecting to database specified by database.yml
>   [ 2013-09-16 14:35:37.4570 4197/b72beb40 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:849 ]: Could not spawn process for group /media/sf_John/product#default: An error occurred while starting up the preloader: it did not write a startup response in time.
>        in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::throwPreloaderSpawnException(const std::string&, Passenger::SpawnException::ErrorKind, boost::shared_ptr&, const boost::shared_ptr&)' (SmartSpawner.h:150)
>        in 'std::string Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::negotiatePreloaderStartup(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::StartupDetails&)' (SmartSpawner.h:558)
>        in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::startPreloader()' (SmartSpawner.h:206)
>        in 'virtual Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::spawn(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&)' (SmartSpawner.h:744)
>        in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (Implementation.cpp:782)
>
> [ 2013-09-16 14:35:37.4578 4197/b60fdb40 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1952 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session. An error occurred while starting up the preloader: it did not write a startup response in time.

Gem list:

```
actionmailer (3.2.14, 3.2.13)
actionpack (3.2.14, 3.2.13)
active_hash (1.0.1, 0.9.14)
activemodel (3.2.14, 3.2.13)
activerecord (3.2.14, 3.2.13)
activeresource (3.2.14, 3.2.13)
activesupport (3.2.14, 3.2.13)
acts_as_paranoid (0.4.2)
addressable (2.3.5, 2.3.4)
american_date (1.1.0)
arbre (1.0.1)
arel (3.0.2)
attr_required (0.0.5)
bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2, 3.1.1, 3.0.1)
better_errors (0.9.0)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
bourbon (3.1.8)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.1)
cancan (1.6.10)
capybara (2.1.0)
childprocess (0.3.9)
chronic (0.10.0, 0.9.1)
chunky_png (1.2.8)
cliver (0.2.1)
coderay (1.0.9)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-rails-source-maps (1.3.6, 1.3.5)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.3, 1.6.2)
compass (0.12.2)
compass-rails (1.0.3)
crack (0.4.1, 0.4.0)
daemon_controller (1.1.4)
daemons (1.1.9)
dalli (2.6.4)
database_cleaner (1.1.1, 0.9.1)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
devise (3.0.3, 3.0.2, 3.0.1, 2.2.4)
devise_oauth2_providable (1.1.2)
diff-lcs (1.2.4)
dotenv (0.8.0)
dragonfly (0.9.15)
draper (1.2.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
ethon (0.6.1, 0.6.0, 0.5.12)
eventmachine (1.0.3)
excon (0.25.3, 0.23.0)
execjs (2.0.1, 1.4.0)
factory_girl (4.2.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
faraday (0.8.8)
faraday_middleware (0.9.0)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
ffaker (1.18.0, 1.16.1)
ffi (1.9.0)
fog (1.15.0, 1.14.0, 1.12.1)
foreman (0.63.0)
formatador (0.2.4)
formtastic (2.2.1)
forward (0.3.2)
fssm (0.2.10)
fuubar (1.2.1, 1.1.1)
gherkin (2.12.1, 2.12.0)
guard (1.8.2, 1.8.1)
guard-rspec (3.0.2)
guard-spork (1.5.1, 1.5.0)
haml (4.0.3)
haml-rails (0.4)
has_scope (0.6.0.rc, 0.5.1)
highline (1.6.19)
hike (1.2.3)
httpclient (2.3.4.1, 2.3.3)
i18n (0.6.5, 0.6.4, 0.6.1)
inherited_resources (1.4.1, 1.4.0)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.3.0)
jquery-ui-rails (4.0.4, 4.0.3)
json (1.7.7)
jwt (0.1.8)
kaminari (0.14.1)
kgio (2.8.0)
kramdown (1.1.0, 1.0.2)
launchy (2.3.0)
listen (1.3.0, 1.2.2)
lumberjack (1.0.4)
mail (2.5.4)
mail_view (1.0.3)
meta_search (1.1.3)
method_source (0.8.2, 0.8.1)
mime-types (1.24, 1.23)
mini_magick (3.6.0)
mini_portile (0.5.1)
mock_redis (0.9.0, 0.8.2, 0.7.0)
modernizr-rails (2.6.2.3)
modular-scale (1.0.6)
mono_logger (1.1.0)
multi_json (1.7.9, 1.7.8, 1.7.7)
multipart-post (1.2.0)
mysql2 (0.3.13, 0.3.11)
net-scp (1.1.2, 1.1.1)
net-ssh (2.6.8, 2.6.7)
newrelic_rpm (3.6.6.147, 3.6.3.111)
nokogiri (1.6.0, 1.5.10)
oily_png (1.1.0)
orm_adapter (0.4.0)
paper_trail (2.7.2)
passenger (4.0.17)
polyamorous (0.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
pry (0.9.12.2)
quiet_assets (1.0.2)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-oauth2 (0.11.0)
rack-protection (1.5.0)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.14, 3.2.13)
railties (3.2.14, 3.2.13)
raindrops (0.11.0)
rake (10.1.0)
rb-fsevent (0.9.3)
rb-inotify (0.9.1, 0.9.0)
rb-kqueue (0.2.0)
rdoc (3.12.2)
redcarpet (3.0.0, 2.3.0)
redis (3.0.4)
redis-namespace (1.3.1, 1.3.0)
request_store (1.0.5)
responders (1.0.0.rc, 0.9.3)
resque (1.24.1)
resque_mailer (2.2.4)
rspec (2.14.1)
rspec-core (2.14.5, 2.14.4, 2.14.3)
rspec-expectations (2.14.2, 2.14.0)
rspec-instafail (0.2.4)
rspec-mocks (2.14.3, 2.14.2, 2.14.1)
rspec-rails (2.14.0)
ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
ruby-progressbar (1.2.0, 1.1.1)
rubygems-bundler (1.2.2)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
safe_yaml (0.9.5, 0.9.4, 0.9.3)
sass (3.2.10, 3.2.9)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
sassy-math (1.5)
shoulda-matchers (2.3.0, 2.2.0)
simple_form (2.1.0)
simplecov (0.7.1)
simplecov-html (0.7.1)
sinatra (1.4.3)
slop (3.4.6, 3.4.5)
spork-rails (3.2.1)
sprockets (2.2.2)
stamp (0.5.0)
state_machine (1.2.0)
subexec (0.2.3)
thin (1.5.1)
thor (0.18.1)
tilt (1.4.1)
travis-artifacts (0.1.0)
treetop (1.4.15, 1.4.14)
turnip (1.1.0)
twilio-ruby (3.10.1, 3.9.0)
typhoeus (0.6.5, 0.6.4, 0.6.3)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
uglifier (2.2.0, 2.1.2, 2.1.1)
unicorn (4.6.3, 4.6.2)
valid_attribute (1.3.1)
vcr (2.5.0)
vegas (0.1.11)
verbs (2.1.3)
warden (1.2.3, 1.2.1)
webmock (1.11.0)
websocket-driver (0.2.3, 0.2.1)
whenever (0.8.4, 0.8.2)
xpath (2.0.0)
```

Answer (score -1):

For me, it works

```
cd <usr name>
rails new myapp 
sudo bundle install 
mkdir /home/<user name>/myapp
chmod 701 /home/myapp
chmod -R 705 /home/<user name>/myapp
chgrp -R www-data /home/<user_name>/myapp
chown -R <user_name> /home/<user_name>
```