# Phusion Passenger startup issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

I've a application on production server.Everything is working fine before, but I've no idea what went wrong, application is not running and throws following error in nginx's error.log file

```
[ 2015-11-26 05:34:16.2247 7383/7fbc4d776700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/ec2-user/deploy/app/kickmarket_eu/current: An error occurred while starting up the preloader: it did not write a startup response in time.
  Error ID: 3b4df3aa
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-hExUDw.html
  Message from application: An error occurred while starting up the preloader: it did not write a startup response in time. Please read <a href="https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems">this article</a> for more information about this problem.<br>
<h2>Raw process output:</h2>
(empty)

[ 2015-11-26 05:34:16.3445 7383/7fbc4e778700 age/Cor/Req/CheckoutSession.cpp:253 ]: [Client 1-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 3b4df3aa. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
[ 2015-11-26 05:34:16.3447 7383/7fbc4e778700 age/Cor/Req/CheckoutSession.cpp:253 ]: [Client 1-2] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 3b4df3aa. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
[ 2015-11-26 05:34:16.3448 7383/7fbc4e778700 age/Cor/Req/CheckoutSession.cpp:253 ]: [Client 1-3] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 3b4df3aa. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
[ 2015-11-26 05:34:16.3448 7383/7fbc4e778700 age/Cor/Req/CheckoutSession.cpp:253 ]: [Client 1-4] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 3b4df3aa. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
App 7631 stdout:
[ 2015-11-26 05:46:47.5415 7383/7fbc4d776700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/ec2-user/deploy/app/kickmarket_eu/current: An error occurred while starting up the preloader: it did not write a startup response in time.
  Error ID: a3b18413
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-43MKgQ.html
  Message from application: An error occurred while starting up the preloader: it did not write a startup response in time. Please read <a href="https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems">this article</a> for more information about this problem.<br>
<h2>Raw process output:</h2>
(empty
```

I looked into [referred link](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems) but didn't get any idea to fix this.
My nginx server is running properly.
I'm using `passenger-5.0.21` and `ruby-2.1.2`. Any suggestion will be appreciated, Thank you

## Update 1 Added /tmp/passenger-error-hExUDw.html file content

```
<body>

    <div id="site_container">
        <div id="site_header">
            <ul class="corporate_identity">
                <li class="logo"><a href="https://www.phusionpassenger.com"><span>Phusion Passenger</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="site_body">
            <h1 class="error_title">Web application could not be started</h1>
            <div id="content">
                An error occurred while starting up the preloader: it did not write a startup response in time. Please read <a href="https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems">this article</a> for more information about this problem.<br>
<h2>Raw process output:</h2>
(empty)

                <dl>
                <dt>Error ID</dt>
                <dd>3b4df3aa</dd>
                <dt>Application root</dt>
                <dd>/home/ec2-user/deploy/app/kickmarket_eu/current</dd>
                <dt>Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV, NODE_ENV and PASSENGER_APP_ENV)</dt>
                <dd>production</dd>

                    <dt>Ruby interpreter command</dt>
                    <dd><pre>/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/wrappers/ruby</pre></dd>

                <dt>User and groups</dt>
                <dd><pre>uid=<wbr>500(ec2-user) gid=<wbr>500(ec2-user) groups=<wbr>500(ec2-user),<wbr>10(wheel)
</pre></dd>
                <dt>Environment variables</dt>
                <dd><pre>LESS_TERMCAP_mb=<wbr>&#27;[01;<wbr>31m
rvm_bin_path=<wbr>/home/ec2-user/.rvm/bin
HOSTNAME=<wbr>ip-172-31-40-110
LESS_TERMCAP_md=<wbr>&#27;[01;<wbr>38;<wbr>5;<wbr>208m
GEM_HOME=<wbr>/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2
LESS_TERMCAP_me=<wbr>&#27;[0m
SHELL=<wbr>/bin/bash
TERM=<wbr>xterm
HISTSIZE=<wbr>1000
IRBRC=<wbr>/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/.irbrc
EC2_AMITOOL_HOME=<wbr>/opt/aws/amitools/ec2
PYTHON_INSTALL_LAYOUT=<wbr>amzn
PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR=<wbr>/tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXXE01n1W
MY_RUBY_HOME=<wbr>/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2
LESS_TERMCAP_ue=<wbr>&#27;[0m
USER=<wbr>ec2-user
_system_type=<wbr>Linux
EC2_HOME=<wbr>/opt/aws/apitools/ec2
rvm_path=<wbr>/home/ec2-user/.rvm
LESS_TERMCAP_us=<wbr>&#27;[04;<wbr>38;<wbr>5;<wbr>111m
PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD=<wbr>true
rvm_prefix=<wbr>/home/ec2-user
MAIL=<wbr>/var/spool/mail/ec2-user
PATH=<wbr>/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:<wbr>/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:<wbr>/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:<wbr>/home/ec2-user/.rvm/bin:<wbr>/sbin:<wbr>/usr/sbin:<wbr>/bin:<wbr>/usr/bin:<wbr>/usr/local/sbin:<wbr>/opt/aws/bin:<wbr>/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:<wbr>/home/ec2-user/bin
PWD=<wbr>/home/ec2-user/deploy/app/kickmarket_eu/current
JAVA_HOME=<wbr>/usr/lib/jvm/jre
AWS_CLOUDWATCH_HOME=<wbr>/opt/aws/apitools/mon
LANG=<wbr>en_US.UTF-8
_system_arch=<wbr>x86_64
_system_version=<wbr>2015.09
HISTCONTROL=<wbr>ignoredups
rvm_version=<wbr>1.26.11 (latest)
HOME=<wbr>/home/ec2-user
SHLVL=<wbr>2
AWS_PATH=<wbr>/opt/aws
rvm_ruby_string=<wbr>ruby-2.1.2
AWS_AUTO_SCALING_HOME=<wbr>/opt/aws/apitools/as
LOGNAME=<wbr>ec2-user
SERVER_SOFTWARE=<wbr>nginx/1.8.0 Phusion_Passenger/5.0.21
CVS_RSH=<wbr>ssh
GEM_PATH=<wbr>/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2:<wbr>/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global
AWS_ELB_HOME=<wbr>/opt/aws/apitools/elb
LESSOPEN=<wbr>||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
rvm_delete_flag=<wbr>0
RUBY_VERSION=<wbr>ruby-2.1.2
_system_name=<wbr>Amazon
LESS_TERMCAP_se=<wbr>&#27;[0m
IN_PASSENGER=<wbr>1
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=<wbr>1
NODE_PATH=<wbr>/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/nodejs_supportlib
RAILS_ENV=<wbr>production
RACK_ENV=<wbr>production
WSGI_ENV=<wbr>production
NODE_ENV=<wbr>production
PASSENGER_APP_ENV=<wbr>production
</pre></dd>
                <dt>Ulimits</dt>
                <dd><pre>Unknown</pre></dd>

                    <dt>System metrics</dt>
                    <dd><pre>------------- General -------------
Kernel version    :<wbr> 4.1.13-18.26.amzn1.x86_64
Uptime            :<wbr> 26m 30s
Load averages     :<wbr> 2.05%,<wbr> 1.83%,<wbr> 1.41%
Fork rate         :<wbr> unknown

------------- CPU -------------
Number of CPUs    :<wbr>    1
Average CPU usage :<wbr> 100%  -- 100% user,<wbr>   0% nice,<wbr>   0% system,<wbr>   0% idle
  CPU 1           :<wbr> 100%  -- 100% user,<wbr>   0% nice,<wbr>   0% system,<wbr>   0% idle
I/O pressure      :<wbr>   0%
  CPU 1           :<wbr>   0%
Interference from other VMs:<wbr>  87%
  CPU 1                    :<wbr>  87%

------------- Memory -------------
RAM total         :<wbr>    995 MB
RAM used          :<wbr>    449 MB (45%)
RAM free          :<wbr>    545 MB
Swap total        :<wbr>   1279 MB
Swap used         :<wbr>      0 MB (0%)
Swap free         :<wbr>   1279 MB
Swap in           :<wbr> unknown
Swap out          :<wbr> unknown

</pre></dd>


                    <dt>General Ruby interpreter information</dt>
                    <dd><pre>RUBY_VERSION =<wbr> 2.1.2
RUBY_PLATFORM =<wbr> x86_64-linux
RUBY_ENGINE =<wbr> ruby
RubyGems version =<wbr> 2.4.8
RubyGems paths =<wbr> [&quot;/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2&quot;,<wbr> &quot;/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global&quot;]
</pre></dd>


                    <dt>Ruby configuration (RbConfig::CONFIG)</dt>
                    <dd><pre>DESTDIR =<wbr>
MAJOR =<wbr> 2
MINOR =<wbr> 1
TEENY =<wbr> 0
PATCHLEVEL =<wbr> 95
INSTALL =<wbr> /usr/bin/install -c
EXEEXT =<wbr>
prefix =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2
ruby_install_name =<wbr> ruby
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME =<wbr> ruby
RUBY_SO_NAME =<wbr> ruby
exec =<wbr> exec
ruby_pc =<wbr> ruby-2.1.pc
PACKAGE =<wbr> ruby
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS =<wbr>  newline.c
USE_RUBYGEMS =<wbr> YES
MANTYPE =<wbr> doc
NROFF =<wbr> /usr/bin/nroff
vendorarchhdrdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/vendor_ruby/x86_64-linux
sitearchhdrdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/site_ruby/x86_64-linux
rubyarchhdrdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/x86_64-linux
vendorhdrdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/vendor_ruby
sitehdrdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/site_ruby
rubyhdrdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0
RUBY_SEARCH_PATH =<wbr>
UNIVERSAL_INTS =<wbr>
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES =<wbr>
configure_args =<wbr>  &apos;--prefix=<wbr>/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2&apos; &apos;--disable-install-doc&apos; &apos;--enable-shared&apos;
vendorarchdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux
vendorlibdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0
vendordir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
sitearchdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux
sitelibdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0
sitedir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby
rubyarchdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux
rubylibdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0
ruby_version =<wbr> 2.1.0
sitearch =<wbr> x86_64-linux
arch =<wbr> x86_64-linux
sitearchincludedir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/include/x86_64-linux
archincludedir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/include/x86_64-linux
sitearchlibdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/x86_64-linux
archlibdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/x86_64-linux
libdirname =<wbr> libdir
RUBY_EXEC_PREFIX =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2
RUBY_LIB_VERSION =<wbr>
RUBY_LIB_VERSION_STYLE =<wbr> 3 /* full */
RI_BASE_NAME =<wbr> ri
ridir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/share/ri
rubysitearchprefix =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/x86_64-linux
rubyarchprefix =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/x86_64-linux
MAKEFILES =<wbr> Makefile GNUmakefile
PLATFORM_DIR =<wbr>
THREAD_MODEL =<wbr> pthread
SYMBOL_PREFIX =<wbr>
EXPORT_PREFIX =<wbr>
COMMON_HEADERS =<wbr>
COMMON_MACROS =<wbr>
COMMON_LIBS =<wbr>
MAINLIBS =<wbr>
ENABLE_SHARED =<wbr> yes
DLDLIBS =<wbr>  -lc
SOLIBS =<wbr> -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED =<wbr> -Wl,<wbr>-R -Wl,<wbr>/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib -L/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib -lruby
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC =<wbr> -Wl,<wbr>-R -Wl,<wbr>/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib -L/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib -lruby-static
LIBRUBYARG =<wbr> -Wl,<wbr>-R -Wl,<wbr>/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib -L/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib -lruby
LIBRUBY =<wbr> libruby.so.2.1.0
LIBRUBY_ALIASES =<wbr> libruby.so.2.1 libruby.so
LIBRUBY_SO =<wbr> libruby.so.2.1.0
LIBRUBY_A =<wbr> libruby-static.a
RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME =<wbr>
rubyw_install_name =<wbr>
EXTDLDFLAGS =<wbr>
EXTLDFLAGS =<wbr>
strict_warnflags =<wbr> -ansi -std=<wbr>iso9899:<wbr>199409
warnflags =<wbr> -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
debugflags =<wbr> -ggdb3
optflags =<wbr> -O3 -fno-fast-math
cxxflags =<wbr>  -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
cflags =<wbr>  -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
cppflags =<wbr>
NULLCMD =<wbr> :<wbr>
DLNOBJ =<wbr> dln.o
INSTALLDOC =<wbr> nodoc
CAPITARGET =<wbr> nodoc
RDOCTARGET =<wbr> nodoc
DTRACE_GLOMMED_OBJ =<wbr>
DTRACE_OBJ =<wbr>
DTRACE_EXT =<wbr> dmyh
EXECUTABLE_EXTS =<wbr>
ARCHFILE =<wbr>
LIBRUBY_RELATIVE =<wbr> no
EXTOUT =<wbr> .ext
RUNRUBY_COMMAND =<wbr> $(MINIRUBY) $(srcdir)/tool/runruby.rb --extout=<wbr>.ext $(RUNRUBYOPT)
PREP =<wbr> miniruby
BTESTRUBY =<wbr> $(MINIRUBY)
CROSS_COMPILING =<wbr> no
TEST_RUNNABLE =<wbr> yes
rubylibprefix =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby
setup =<wbr> Setup
EXTSTATIC =<wbr>
STRIP =<wbr> strip -S -x
TRY_LINK =<wbr>
LIBPATHENV =<wbr> LD_LIBRARY_PATH
RPATHFLAG =<wbr>  -Wl,<wbr>-R%1$-s
LIBPATHFLAG =<wbr>  -L%1$-s
LINK_SO =<wbr>
LIBEXT =<wbr> a
DLEXT2 =<wbr>
DLEXT =<wbr> so
LDSHAREDXX =<wbr> g++ -shared
LDSHARED =<wbr> gcc -shared
CCDLFLAGS =<wbr> -fPIC
STATIC =<wbr>
ARCH_FLAG =<wbr>
DLDFLAGS =<wbr>
ALLOCA =<wbr>
codesign =<wbr>
POSTLINK =<wbr> :<wbr>
WERRORFLAG =<wbr> -Werror
CHDIR =<wbr> cd -P
RMALL =<wbr> rm -fr
RMDIRS =<wbr> rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty -p
RMDIR =<wbr> rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty
CP =<wbr> cp
RM =<wbr> rm -f
PKG_CONFIG =<wbr> pkg-config
PYTHON =<wbr>
DOXYGEN =<wbr> doxygen
DOT =<wbr>
DTRACE =<wbr>
MAKEDIRS =<wbr> /bin/mkdir -p
MKDIR_P =<wbr> /bin/mkdir -p
INSTALL_DATA =<wbr> /usr/bin/install -c -m 644
INSTALL_SCRIPT =<wbr> /usr/bin/install -c
INSTALL_PROGRAM =<wbr> /usr/bin/install -c
SET_MAKE =<wbr>
LN_S =<wbr> ln -s
NM =<wbr> nm
DLLWRAP =<wbr>
WINDRES =<wbr>
OBJCOPY =<wbr> :<wbr>
OBJDUMP =<wbr> objdump
ASFLAGS =<wbr>
AS =<wbr> as
AR =<wbr> ar
RANLIB =<wbr> ranlib
try_header =<wbr>
CC_VERSION =<wbr> gcc -v
COUTFLAG =<wbr> -o
OUTFLAG =<wbr> -o
CPPOUTFILE =<wbr> -o conftest.i
GNU_LD =<wbr> yes
LD =<wbr> ld
GCC =<wbr> yes
EGREP =<wbr> /bin/grep -E
GREP =<wbr> /bin/grep
CPP =<wbr> gcc -E
CXXFLAGS =<wbr>  -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
CXX =<wbr> g++
OBJEXT =<wbr> o
CPPFLAGS =<wbr>
LDFLAGS =<wbr> -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,<wbr>-export-dynamic
CFLAGS =<wbr>  -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC
CC =<wbr> gcc
NACL_SDK_VARIANT =<wbr>
NACL_SDK_ROOT =<wbr>
NACL_TOOLCHAIN =<wbr>
target_os =<wbr> linux
target_vendor =<wbr> unknown
target_cpu =<wbr> x86_64
target =<wbr> x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
host_os =<wbr> linux-gnu
host_vendor =<wbr> unknown
host_cpu =<wbr> x86_64
host =<wbr> x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
RUBY_VERSION_NAME =<wbr> ruby-2.1.0
RUBYW_BASE_NAME =<wbr> rubyw
RUBY_BASE_NAME =<wbr> ruby
build_os =<wbr> linux-gnu
build_vendor =<wbr> unknown
build_cpu =<wbr> x86_64
build =<wbr> x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
RUBY_RELEASE_DATE =<wbr> 2014-05-08
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION =<wbr> 2.1.2
target_alias =<wbr>
host_alias =<wbr>
build_alias =<wbr>
LIBS =<wbr> -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm
ECHO_T =<wbr>
ECHO_N =<wbr> -n
ECHO_C =<wbr>
DEFS =<wbr>
mandir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/share/man
localedir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/share/locale
libdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib
psdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/share/doc/ruby
pdfdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/share/doc/ruby
dvidir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/share/doc/ruby
htmldir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/share/doc/ruby
infodir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/share/info
docdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/share/doc/ruby
oldincludedir =<wbr> /usr/include
includedir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/include
localstatedir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/var
sharedstatedir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/com
sysconfdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/etc
datadir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/share
datarootdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/share
libexecdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/libexec
sbindir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/sbin
bindir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin
exec_prefix =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2
PACKAGE_URL =<wbr>
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT =<wbr>
PACKAGE_STRING =<wbr>
PACKAGE_VERSION =<wbr>
PACKAGE_TARNAME =<wbr>
PACKAGE_NAME =<wbr>
PATH_SEPARATOR =<wbr> :<wbr>
SHELL =<wbr> /bin/sh
archdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux
topdir =<wbr> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux
</pre></dd>



                    <dt>Ruby load path ($LOAD_PATH)</dt>
                    <dd><pre>/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux
</pre></dd>


                    <dt>Ruby loaded libraries ($LOADED_FEATURES)</dt>
                    <dd><pre>enumerator.so
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb
thread.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux/thread.so
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/errors.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/version.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/platform.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/util/stringio.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/constants.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpio.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/operating_system.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/ruby.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/binary_compatibility.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/buildout/ruby/ruby-2.1.2-x86_64-linux/passenger_native_support.so
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux/socket.so
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/socket.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux/pathname.so
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/pathname.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_enhancements.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_io_enhancements.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/base64.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/public_api.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/debug_logging.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/shellwords.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils/shellwords.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/message_channel.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/message_client.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils/native_support_utils.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils/unseekable_socket.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux/stringio.so
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils/tee_input.rb
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb
</pre></dd>

                </dl>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="site_footer">
            <!--
               You are free to modify the footer as you see fit,
               but we kindly ask of you to preserve to following
               text. Thank you.
            -->
            <div class="container">
                Powered by <a href="https://www.phusionpassenger.com/">Phusion Passenger</a>,
                <tt>mod_rails</tt> / <tt>mod_rack</tt> for Apache and Nginx.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: What are teh "Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-43MKgQ.html"?

Comment: @BradWerth I updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passenger: internal server error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328326/passenger-internal-server-error)

Comment: Nothing is jumping out at me, but you might benefit from https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems . It looks like a common cause of this error is writing to stdout in your app...

Comment: Thanks a lot, But I tried every solution nothing worked for me

Comment: I'm reinstalling passenger, Hope this will work :)

Comment: An alternative might be to try a new empty rails app, and see what it does with that. Then you'll know if it's choking on your app...

Comment: Okay brother. I'll be on it after installation completed. I'll let you know if there is any update

Comment: Hello @BradWerth, After re-installation I'm not getting previous error.
I'm sure this is not the good way.

Answer (score 2):

**Passenger: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.**

Include Passenger Timeout in passenger.conf file

```
PassengerStartTimeout 120
```

If you have installed apache-passenger module , find the passenger load path add this below line .

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.41/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.41
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
PassengerStartTimeout 120
</IfModule>
```